# Print Function - Linked-List c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with this printList Function. I am getting the following compiler error:

> No operator "<<" matches these operands.

The function is as follows:

```
void printList(const List& theList)
{   
for(Node* i = theList.getFirst(); i != theList.getLast(); ++i)
{
    cout << *i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

I have the following as well,

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>
```

I am thinking my print function is just way off base. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here are my classes, I don't have a List::Iterator. What would you suggest?

```
class List
{
private:
    int nodeListTotal;
    Node* first;
    Node* last;

public:
    //Constructor
    List();

    void push_back(Node*);
    void push_front(Node*);
    Node* pop_back();
    Node* pop_front();
    Node* getFirst() const;
    Node* getLast() const;
    int getListLength() const;
    void retrieve(int index, int& dataItem) const;
};

class Node
{
private:
    string dataItem;
    string dataUnit;
    int unitTotal;
    Node* next;

public:
    //Constructor
    Node();

    Node(int, string, string);

    string getDescription( );
    void setDescription(string);

    string getQuantityName();
    void setQuantityName(string);

    int getQuantityNumber();
    void setQuantityNumber(int);

    Node* getNext( );
    void setNext(Node*);
};
```

Comment: Try something simpler: `Node n; cout << n;`. If that doesn't work, then you forgot to define `ostream &Node::operator<<(ostream &)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload `operator<<` for Node type:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std:::ostream& os, const Node& node)
{
    os << node.getQuantityName() << " " << node.getDescription();
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my classes I don't have List::Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says

```
No operator "<<" matches these operands.
```

you don't have the << operator defined for your class.

Answer (score 0):

In your `printList()` function, replace `cout << *i << " ";` with
`cout << i->getDescription() << endl;`